# Beetle infection

Tags: pests, urban-gardening

[image: Beetle]

Having the infestation of the beetle above in the gardening pots. The grub of the beetle is causing trouble to the young plants and the soil loses water retention due to the pupa stage which forms soil shells.

Could any one recommend a way to eradicate or control this in organic way?

What could be done with the current soil? Should it be completely removed?

Comment: Will chickens eat these beetles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Calligrapha genus of some variety. Oregon State suggests using Novodor (Bt tenebrionus) on the grubs of [Californica](http://oregonstate.edu/dept/nurspest/Calligrapha%20californica.html), so it might work for this guy.

EDIT: A few pictures, as I realize the only link I provided looks nothing like your example: [Here](https://mczbase.mcz.harvard.edu/specimen_images/publications/Breviora_541.pdf).

Comment: Pretty sure its a miniaturized cow... honey... I shrunk the cow.

Comment: Thank you very much for your immediate response. I will try to get a Novodor equivalent in India. I will wait for any other recommendation for fixing the soil with larval and pupal infestation. If I don't get any more answers I will mark this as accepted.

Comment: Checking back in... Could not find an equivalent of Novodor. Infestation is still there. Any other alternatives?

Comment: Any BT available? Bacillus thuringiensis galleriae (BTG) came out in 2015 and works on beetles.

Comment: Now I could see Bt Kurstaki available on Amazon here. Will this work on this beetle larva?